# Set background-size: contain on an overlay

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to apply an overlay on top of a `background-image`, where the image has an attribute `background-size: contain`. For the overlay that I want to apply on top of it, it doesn't have a background image. All it has is a black background color with an opacity:

```
.overlay {
    background-color: black;
    background-size: contain; /* this isn't working */
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

The image that I want to overlay is 600x600. I want the same to be applied on the overlay too, but I can't because it's not an image; it's simply a black background. How can I get the same square dimensions for the overlay without setting a hard-coded width and without using `background-size: contain`?

Comment: Please provide enough code for a complete working example. HTML with the appropriate CSS.

Comment: `background-size: contain` only works on background images.

Comment: How do you expect to work with a background-color ? there is no proportion to keep ...

Comment: You don't _need_ background-size for just black. How large is this element with class="overlay"?

Comment: I don't understand. You want you Overlay background-color to fill the whole div? Because that's the default. Are you using an image to fill in the color? In that case use `background-size: cover` to fill the whole div.

Comment: @MrLister the element is 600x600. I want the overlay to lay right on top of the image, which has `background-size: contain` applied. I don't want to specify a `width` on the overlay because it won't adjust in accordance to the image.

Comment: Aaaa you have a background-iamge with contain and want to overlay jus the bg img ?

Comment: If you want the overlay to be the same size, and in the same location, as the image, you need different CSS than what you have here. How are the overlay and the image related? I mean, how can the overlay know that it has to have the same size as the image?

Comment: Is the effect you're after simply to make the image appear darker?

Comment: @MrLister err yeah, that's essentially what I'm doing. I just want to overlay the image to make it appear darker. I thought an overlay would do the trick.

Comment: if you'd share a full snippet showing us what you did , you would already have an efficient  answer and why/where you went wrong (poor question makes poor answers ;) )

Comment: @GCyrillus While the question could have been clearer from the start, I question the foregone conclusion that the answers are bad!

Comment: @MrLister answers can only be average guesses  .... wich might confuse a bit more the OP :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want simply for the image to come out darker than it really is, you could put it in a container with a black background and give the image itself a 50% opacity.
By making the container an inline-block, it will shape itself to the size of the image inside, so you won't have to specify an explicit size.

```css
.container {
  background:black;
  display:inline-block;
}
.container img {
  opacity:.5;
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/30Bby.jpg">
</div>
```

For reference, the picture itself looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if you want an overlaying transparent div check this out. I usually do it this way. i have a container div containing my background image and black colour div with required opacity to 0.5 (or any other value).

working fiddle  https://jsfiddle.net/am2hyf3d/

set the containers width and height to a fixed value

```
#container{
height:300px;
width:300px;
}
```

i set the width and height of both the divs inside the container to occupy the containers entire space

```
#overlay{
height:100%;
width:100%;
background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

a few ways to darken a background-image without an extra element:

```css
div {/* commun css for demo divs */
width:180px;
height:180px;
margin:10px;
background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/180/180);
color:white
}
.gradient {
background:linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.5),rgba(0,0,0,0.5)),url(http://lorempixel.com/180/180);
}
.shadow {
box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 180px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
.blend {
background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
background-blend-mode:multiply;
}
/* extra for layout */
div {
display:inline-flex;
vertical-align:top;
align-items:center;
justify-content:center;
text-align:center;
font-size:2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="gradient">darken gradient</div>
<div class="shadow">darken shadow</div>
<div>plain normal</div>

<div class="blend">darken blend-mode</div>
```